# Weird loop when booting into a LiveCD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 16.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop computer alongside windows 10 Pro and I'm facing a rather weird behavior as soon as I boot into it using a live CD.

[Short YouTube Clip of my Issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1C-UgsE2PG4)

It's not my first time installing Unix or trying to boot into a LiveCD and I did manage to boot into it on this specific computer just a couple of weeks ago to reformat a drive but now I've tried like 10 times using different USBs and also redownloading the ISO just to make sure I don't have a corrupted image or something.

Any thoughts what it could be?.

- Edit to add extra info: I just went ahead and installed 16.04 in my computer and the same outcome. It gets to the login screen and starts looping over and over again (and this is before installing vga drivers or anything). I also installed 15.10 which worked perfectly and then updated it to 16.04 and as soon as I rebooted and got into the new version the login loop started.